# How to disappear optionmenu when CheckButton is 0

Tags: python, tkinter

i need to not show optionmenu when CheckButton is 0
When "Select port type" is unselected option menu should be hidden

```
from tkinter import *
window = Tk()
def print_selection2():
    value_inside = StringVar(window)
    if var1.get() == 1:
        value_inside.set("Select port type")
        options_list2 = ["lol1", "lol2"]
        question_menu = OptionMenu(window, value_inside, *options_list2).grid(row=2, column=1)
    elif var1.get() == 0:
        options_list2 = ["lol1", "lol2"]
        question_menu = OptionMenu(window, value_inside, *options_list2).grid(row=2, column=1)
        question_menu.configure(state="disabled")

var1 = IntVar()
c1 = Checkbutton(window, text="Port change", variable=var1, onvalue=1, offvalue=0, command=print_selection2).grid(row=1,column=1, sticky=W)

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: "lol1", "lol2"...

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to use the checkbox to toggle the visibility of the option menu, you need to create the option menu once (initially hidden) and set its visibility inside `print_selection2()`:

```py
from tkinter import *

window = Tk()

def print_selection2():
    if var1.get() == 1:
        question_menu.grid(row=2, column=1) # show it
    else:
        question_menu.grid_remove()         # hide it

var1 = IntVar()
Checkbutton(window, text="Port change", variable=var1, onvalue=1, offvalue=0, command=print_selection2).grid(row=1,column=1, sticky=W)

options_list2 = ["lol1", "lol2"]
value_inside = StringVar(window, value="Select port type")
question_menu = OptionMenu(window, value_inside, *options_list2)

window.mainloop()
```